# I am trying to prevent an error if the user tries to divide 10/'dog'. Even after using exception I still get error

Tags: python, typeerror, valueerror

[Still getting Type and Value Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tDAxs.png)

```
def my_divider(a,b):         
    try:return a/b 
    
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        return"Error: You cannot divide a number by 0"
    
    except TypeError:         
        a=float(a)
        b=float(b)
        return a/b
    
    except ValueError:
        return"Please enter an integer"
  
var1=10
var2='dog'
print(my_divider(var1,var2))
```

Comment: Please post your actual code here, not just a link to an image.

Comment: Post your code please, not an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll echo what @dkamins is saying here but I need the rep so I'll take a stab here.

The code you're cooking looks so close, you'll kick yourself when you see it. Great use of the try except clause! You're looking like a python pro already. Yes, the error occurs when you try to assign `b = float(b)` when `isinstance(b,str)` but I see, I think, you trying to catch that exception. But since it is inline with a *separate* try-except clause, it is behaving how you're seeing. So, something like:

```
def my_divisor(a,b):

  try:

    return a/b

  except ZeroDivisionError:

    print("You cannot divide by the number 0")

    return None
  
  except TypeError:

    try:

      a = float(a)
      b = float(b)

      return a/b

    except ValueError:

      print('Error converting type of a, b to numeric. Just put in some numbers, pls')

      return None
```

Be careful!!! We didn't handle something here. What would `my_divisor(40,"0")` return? I think you got it from here friend!

Answer (score 0):

You are catching `TypeError` which is correct. If you return some string back from this `except` block your program will run without any issue and print the returned string. But you are raising another `ValueError` by converting `dog` into `string`.

Keep in mind that all these `except` blocks are for one `try` block. What you are trying to do is ok if I cause another exception in handling first exception, I will write another except block, that will not work. You will have to write another `try-except` block.

Comment: Yes, but this is just too complex. What actually do you want?

Comment: You want to input an integer ? then why are you converting to `float` ? You want to keep asking until user inputs an integer ?

Comment: You can write `return float(a) / float(b)` inside `try` block, in this way you can catch the `ValueError` as well as `TypeError` and act accordingly.

Comment: Thank you. The code needed to be restructured and I had to add a try block like you said

Answer (score -1):

First of all, please paste your code in the question.

In your case, the TypeError is triggering, but you are then causing a secondary ValueError exception when calling `float('dog')`.

To fix this, you have to first decide what you WANT to happen in this case.

Comment: Kept trying and the code came out looking weird sorry.

Comment: I would like it to simply tell the user to "Enter an integer"

Comment: Then you need to restructure your code to loop over input+calculation+print until it succeeds. The exception handler can't do this work. It will just catch exception (and maybe print an error) so the containing loop will know to run again.